# Is there any way to automate this scenario in Cypress for drop down lists for Selecting Random country and its states/region randomly?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

I am automating the page. in the drop-down, I am trying to choose a country randomly every time I run the test case. but how to map random country chosen by the `math.random` function where I added all the countries into the array.

```javascript
var country =[" "]
var randomItem = country[Math.floor(Math.random() * country.length)];
```

If India is selected randomly by the above code, I need to choose any one of the states from India randomly from the second drop down.

Comment: Why not apply the same `math.random` logic for states too ?

Comment: The Idea is to map countries and states if Math. random chooses India a country, no guarantee that it will choose states present in India in following dropdown. and for 200 + countries I have many states, don't know how to do that keeping all stats in arrayy.

Comment: Is there a request that contains all the countries and/or region/states?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Fixtures folder create a `state.json` file like this.

```js
{
   "India":[
      "State1",
      "State2",
      "State3"
   ],
   "US":[
      "State",
      "State2",
      "State3"
   ]
}
```

Assuming your dropdown elements are `select` and `option`.

```js
//Select the Country
cy.get('option')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    //select by index
    cy.get('country-dropdown-selector').select(Math.floor(Math.random() * len))
  })

//Retrieve the innertext of selected option
cy.get('country-dropdown-selector')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((country) => {
    cy.fixture('state.json').then((state) => {
      //From the extracted country, go to json file,
      //and get the length of state array
      cy.get('state-dropdown-selector').select(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * state[`${country}`].length)
      )
    })
  })
```